# How to add mutilple dynamic items on listview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listview

I have two pages.The first page contains form with required fields and also a submit button(with validations).And In the second page Listview should be there. So, when i clicked on the Submit button in first page ,the entire fields should be display on the list.
I have used local storage for saving the data in the second page.It is perfect.But the data is not displaying exactly on the list.And I want to add multiple items dynamically in the firstpage,So that multiple items which are added by me  can be seen in second page.
Here are my two pages code.
new.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html >
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/new.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./js-css/development-bundle/themes/start/jquery.ui.all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="js-css/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-css/development-bundle/jquery-1.10.2.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-css/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-css/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
   var pickerOpts = {
  appendText: "",
  defaultDate: "+5",
  showOtherMonths: true,
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
 };  

  $("#strtd").datepicker({
   minDate: 0
  });

  $("#sub").datepicker({ 
  maxDate: new Date, 
  minDate: new Date(2007, 6, 12)
  });

  $('#strtd').focus(function() {
  this.blur();
  });
  $('#sub').focus(function() {
  this.blur();
  });

  });
  function back() {
 window.open("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
   }
 //form validation
 function validateForm() {
  localStorage.setItem("RecordName", document.myForm.RecordName.value);
  localStorage.setItem("StartedDate", document.myForm.StartedDate.value);
  localStorage.setItem("SubmitedDate", document.myForm.SubmitedDate.value); 
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
  var y= document.forms["myForm"]["strtd"].value;
  var z= document.forms["myForm"]["sub"].value;
   if (x==null || x=="") {
    alert("Record name must be filled out");
    return false;
   }
   else if (y==null || y=="") {
    alert("Started Date must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
   else if (z==null || z=="") {
    alert("Submitted Date must be filled out");
    return false;
     }
   else {
   alert("New Record Created");
     }
     }
   </script>
  </head>
    <body>
   <form name="myForm" id="form" type="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()"  action="lead.html">
  <div id="top"> New Record</div>
     <div>
   <h5>Record Name <input type="text" name="RecordName" id="name"></h5>
   </div>
    <div >
    <h5>Started Date <input id="strtd" type="text" name="StartedDate"></h5>
   </div>
    <div>
    <h5>Submitted Date <input id="sub" type="text" name="SubmitedDate"></h5>
   </div><br>
      <div align="center">
    <input  type="submit" id="submit"   value="Submit" >
    </div>
     </form>
    <div align="center">
   <button id="cancel" onclick="back()">Back</button>
     </div>
    </body>
     </html>
```

and my second page lead.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/lead.css" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"> </script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>

     <script>
   function mylead1() 
    {
  window.open("file:///android_asset/www/editlead.html");
     }
   function mylead2() 
    {
   window.open("file:///android_asset/www/editlead.html");
     }
  function mylead3()
    {
  window.open("file:///android_asset/www/editlead.html");
     }
   function onBackKey()
     {
   window.open("file:///android_asset/www/new.html");
      }
   </script>
   </head>
  <body id="lead">
 <div id="top" align="center" > Leads </div>
   <img  id="plus" src="./images/plus.png" onclick="onBackKey()" >
   <div data-role="page"  style="margin-top:100px;" >
   <div data-role="main" id="content" style="min-height:60px;">
   <ul id="unorder" data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-dividertheme="b">
   <li id="list" data-role="list-divider">
   <label id="label1"  > </label><br>
   <label id="label2"></label><br>
   <label id="label3"></label>
   <img  id="arrow" src="./images/Arrow@2x.png" style="margin-left:250px" onclick="mylead1()">
   </li>  
  </ul>      
   </div>
  </div> 
   </body>
   <script>
  //local storage
      document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML= localStorage.getItem("RecordName"); 
      document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML= localStorage.getItem("StartedDate"); 
     document.getElementById("label3").innerHTML= localStorage.getItem("SubmitedDate"); 
     </script>
   <script>
    $("#submit").click( function() {
   $("ul").append("<li></li>").listview("refresh");
   li.text("#label1");
    $("#unorder").append(li);
    $("#unorder").listview("refresh");
     })
      </script>
    </html>
```

My requirement is to get the added data(in new.html) dynamically on second page(lead.html)
`Please guide me for resolving it.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

local storage is working fine , so m not focusing on it.
Here concern is displaying all data from first page in second that too in list format

this is the most simplest way to do this,

**ON FIRST PAGE**
on form submit suppose you are calling one function name **redirect**

```
function redirect()
{
   var form = $("form[name='myForm']");
   form_data = form.serialize();

   window.location = "secondpage.html?"+form_data  // eg: secondpage.html?single=Single2&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&radio=radio1
}
```

**ON SECOND PAGE**

function which will parse  url and give parameters as objects

```
    var re = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g;
    var decodeRE = /\+/g;  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
    var decode = function (str) {return decodeURIComponent( str.replace(decodeRE, " ") );};
    $.parseParams = function(query) {
        var params = {}, e;
        while ( e = re.exec(query) ) { 
            var k = decode( e[1] ), v = decode( e[2] );
            if (k.substring(k.length - 2) === '[]') {
                k = k.substring(0, k.length - 2);
                (params[k] || (params[k] = [])).push(v);
            }
            else params[k] = v;
        }
        return params;
    };



var url = window.location.href ; //'www.example.com?ferko=suska&ee=huu';
    var parameters = $.parseParams( url.split('?')[1] || '' ); // object { ferko: 'suska', ee: 'huu' }

   var li='';
   $.each( parameters, function( key, value ) {
    //    write html code 
   li += "<li>"+value+"</li>"
});

$("ul").html(li);

<ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..I have tried the above code..listview is not displaying..:( but i can see the data

Comment: And also I have a question..Whether Listview should be created in new.html page or in lead.html page?What Iam thinking is..It should be created after  alert("New Record Created"); in new.html right? If not please suggest me where the Listview should be created?

Comment: yes, it should get created in new i.e. second html page - where you will land after redirection, sorry while appending <li> i forget to add semicol (;) at the sentence end , might tat can b the issue, else i think everything is fine, u can try for it

Comment: Thanks Sawant :) .BTW Iam not gng to use any url's in my sample project. Can you please check my code below